# Django model objects do not load in Form in testing environment

Tags: django, testing

Using Django 2.1.3

Getting a strange error here; I have a form multiplechoicefield that draws its choices from the values existing in a model in the database.

```
class ChartForm(Form):
    P_CHOICES = tuple((p["p"], p["p"]) for p in VAR.objects.all().values("p"))

    p = MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=P_CHOICES, initial=P_CHOICES[0][1])
```

I am trying to run tests for a *different app* in the project. It throws the following error:

```
  File "/code/pyyc/forms.py", line 31, in ChartForm
    p = MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=P_CHOICES, initial=P_CHOICES[0][1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I assumed it was just because the model objects weren't loaded. So I added in the fixtures from the VAR app.

And yet, it still throws the error. Presumably, the Form is render *before* the test database is compiled ... ?

So I am now editing the Form so that P_CHOICES is done manually, but this is obviously not ideal for the test environment.

Anyone ever come across this? Is there a smart hack for this that doesn't involve commenting out lines in the Form every time you want to test?

Comment: Can you try printing the output of `VAR.objects.all()` to know for sure that form is rendering before the db is created.

Comment: thx. I did. Returns None

Comment: You should really use a ModelChoiceField with a queryset fur this sort of thing.

Comment: not sure i understand. all() is a queryset. any queryset will not load appropriately i don't believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your presumption I think is correct. The class level attribute `P_CHOICES` is created when Python first loads the `ChartForm` class, before the test has actually started running. The fixtures are installed later as part of the test's `setUpClass()` (called by the test framework) but by that point `P_CHOICES` has already been defined and is empty.

You could try creating the `MultipleChoiceField` without its `choices` and `initial` attributes, and then set those in the form's `__init__` when the data is available. For example:

```
class ChartForm(Form):
    p = MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        p_choices = tuple((p["p"], p["p"]) for p in VAR.objects.all().values("p"))
        # Now we have the data we can set the attributes
        self.fields['p'].choices = p_choices
        self.fields['p'].initial = p_choices[0][1]
```